# Добавление элементов в вектор

Tags: c++, функции, локальные-переменные

пишу программу, часть ее должна добавлять элементы в вектор либо ручным либо рандомным способами. Элементы добавляет, но при перезапуске цикла теряет старые значения( либо ячто-то делаю не так) помогите разобраться, вот тетсовая версия проги

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void fulling_ruch()
{
    int a = 0;
    int i, m, g;
    int b;
    int p = 0;
    int h;
    vector<int> arr;

    while (a != 3)
    {
        cout << "1. Добавить элемент вручную.\n "
                "2. Добавить элемент рандомом \n "
                "3. Закончить добавление элементов\n";
        cin >> a;

        if (a == 1)
        {
            cin >> b;
            arr.push_back(b);
            p++;
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            b = rand() % 100;
            arr.push_back(b);
            p++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Результат: " << endl;;

    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int choise = 0;
    int vi = 0;
    bool check = true;

    while (check)
    {
        cout << "1. Добавление элемента (заполнение)";
        cin >> choise;

        switch (choise)
        {
            case 1:
                fulling_ruch();
                break;

            case 2:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вектор - локальная переменная функции `fulling_ruch`, и по выходе из нее он полностью уничтожается.

Или делайте его глобальным, или передавайте в функцию ссылку на вектор.

Comment: а чтобы передать ссылку на вектор его нужно сначала в мейне написать?

Comment: Да. Или в другом месте, но так, чтоб он был вне вашего цикла и вне функции, в которую вы его передаете..